# How can I do multiple snapping of vector layers in QGIS?

Tags: snapping

I have a network of a transport system that I created from 1970-2013. However, the accuracy is letting me down as I used different snapping settings throughout the process. Is there a plugin or a way that I can correct each line (and align each method of transport which uses the same stretch of road) without using the node tool?

I have attempted to use the traceDIGITISE plugin but it didnt work for me.